# permalink structure postname and wp internal routing (301 vs 404)

Tags: permalinks, redirect, 404-error, routing

I don't understand the following behavior:

to verify, I have a fresh default/standard wp installation (no themes, no plugins)

I change in settings the permalink structure to `"post name"`.

I create two pages and call them `eg "sub1" and "sub2"`.

now I create a 3rd-page "test" with "sub1" as the parent.

so the link `.../sub1/test` works as expected
but if I call `.../sub2/test` (which does not exist) I would expect a 404.
instead, I can see a 301 and the page "test" under .../sub1 is displayed.

I tested this on many different WordPress installations (and versions)
it seems to be the default behavior with permalink set to "post name"

but technically that's a wrong implementation.

is there a reason for this implementation and is there a way to "correct" this with some hooks ???